# Какие характеристики сервера более важны для mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, сервер

На сайте будет большая БД (около 200Gb).
В разных таблицах 60-200 миллионов строк.

Выбираю выделенный сервер.

Что более приоритетно для mysql?
2 процессора, 8 ядер 2,4 герца
или
1 процессор, 4 ядра и 3,2 герца

Цена на серверы одинаковая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Традиционно одной из важнейших характеристик процессора, которую часто упускают из вида, является размер кеш памяти. От этого в значительной степени зависит цена процессора. Обращение к кешу примерно в десять раз быстрее обращения к оперативке, так что если есть возможность выбирать - выбираем процы с большим объемом кеша.

Как я понимаю, память у нас ECC - с контролем четности, ну, сервер же всё таки?

Идём дальше.

Быстрые серверные процессоры с не очень большим кол-вом ядер часто используются там, где есть понятие "цена лицензии на одно ядро" (ну, то есть, в оракловских базах, лицензия там стоит дороже аппаратного обеспечения)

У Вас - бесплатный MySql, так что смело можно выбирать сервер с большим количеством ядер

Вот такие соображения!